# Why does LM324 Op-amp send out max voltage when I got 0V at the non inverter input?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have this circuit.
The goal is that it going to control the current loop by using the NPN-transistor. My problem here is that 0V results that the output from the Op-amp is near 24V. Why?

[image]

If I'm increasing the voltage a little bit, then I got this.

[image]

And even better, If I implement a schottky diode, then I got this.

[image]

So why does the output goes to near 24V when the non inverting input is 0V?

Comment: There should be a pull-down resistor at the base of the NPN transistor. Most op amps can not output a voltage equal to the bias voltages (24V and GND in this case), so the output can't go to zero. Probably better to reduce 10k to lower value.

Comment: @Ernesto Thank you! I will try that!

Comment: @Ernesto Did not work. Are you sure about there should be a pull-down resistor (e.g 10K) before the base of the NPN transistor?

Comment: There doesn't need to be a pull down @DanielMårtensson - always check someone's reputation before starting a wild goose chase LOL. Falstad isn't that good.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I should have qualified my statement as I think this might fix it. I think now that 0V is not a voltage source but a open connection, maybe try adding 0V voltage source?

Comment: @Ernesto 0V is an microcontroller DAC output.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes. Falstad is bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks OK in my simulator: -

[image]

0 volts in produces near enough 0 volts out (well, 7.847 μV) with a drive level from the LM324 of around 200 mV.

If I increase V1 to 100 mV, it all makes sense too: -

[image]

I suspect that Falstad (is that your sim?) is having problems (after all, it's pretty much a toy when it comes to sim tools) but, importantly, the LM324 will never have problems with inputs or outputs close to 0 volts because it was designed to encompass the negative supply rail, especially so the inputs.

Comment: Great! So Flastad have some issues here. What software are you using?

Comment: Microcap 12 - it is currently free.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: https://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm - choose the top executable. Please let me know how you get on with the download and install.

Comment: I'm Ubuntu user. So I till try it with Wine.

Comment: It is probably off topic, but why do you prefer MicroCap over LTSpice? I never heard of that tool before.

Comment: @jusaca I've been using microcap since circa 2005 and LTSpice has a few anomalies I don't like (differential time measurement for one and not as well-rounded as microcap).

Comment: @Andyaka Download and install? I just downloaded the CD version and unzip it, then i run `wine mc12.exe` and now I can run it under Linux.

Comment: @Andyaka never heard about Micro Cap. Only LTSpice. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The LM324 model (or the simulation) is seriously broken.

LM324 input common mode range includes the negative (and a bit more) so this should never happen for non-inverting input within 100mV of 0V. (If you drive the non-inverting input well below 0V, the output can be driven high, but that's not happening here).

[image]

Raise the non-inverting input to 500mV and it outputs a negative voltage. That is never going to happen either.

[image]

Suggest not wasting time with this software. LTspice is another serious option.

Comment: +1 for LTSpice since it runs very well with wine, like he mentioned